# Ionic 5 Modal only displaying buttons and nothing else - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

so i've been trying to use the `IonModal` on Ionic 5 using React. However, when displaying elements inside of the modal, **only buttons** get displayed. Has anybody encountered this before?
To clarify, when the modal is opened, only the Submit and Cancel buttons show, but I am expecting the `IonInput` and the `div` with the `h1` to appear also.

Imports:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import { checkAuthenticated, load_user } from "./actions/auth";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "./App.css";
import campimg from "./assets/img/campimg.jpeg";
import backpack from "./assets/img/backpack.png";
import { useCurrentLocation, geolocationOptions } from "./actions/spots";
import {
  IonButton,
  IonContent,
  IonInput,
  IonModal,
  IonPage,
} from "@ionic/react";
```

```
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);
```

```
 <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonModal isOpen={showModal}>
          <div>
            <h1>Hello User! You can enter data here:</h1>
          </div>
          <IonInput placeholder="Title"></IonInput>
          <IonButton shape="round" class="button_primary_white_text">
            Submit
          </IonButton>
          <IonButton
            shape="round"
            class="button_secondary_white_text"
            onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
          >
            Cancel
          </IonButton>
        </IonModal>
        <h1>Hello {name["first_name"]}!</h1>
        <IonButton
          shape="round"
          class="button_secondary_white_text"
          onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
        >
          Add Spot
        </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
   </IonPage>
```

Comment: did you import everything? show the code for the whole component

Comment: Updated just there with the imports. They seem to be fine, especially since the modal works fine, it just doesn't display anything else other than the buttons.

Comment: i just droped you modal code into this project and it works fine... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gv5s7a?file=src/App.js

Comment: Strange, I'm gonna keep digging to find out the reason and will update the question accordingly. Thanks for the help!